# MVC and aspx - setting the default page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a website which is running in asp.net webforms. I want to change this to MVC application(new modules will be developed in mvc pattern). For now I have the home page (default.aspx) page running in webforms and I would like to continue the same in MVC too as changing the page is not possible now. For instance if i type in www.example.com it has to go to www.example.com/default.aspx instead of getting to home controller and ActionResult Index().

I have created an MVC project for the same and adding the asp.net webforms modules to this application.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a matter of removing your default route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { Controller = "Home", Action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Set it to:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```